# Retrieving rows that shares the same (Duplicated) PrescriptionID but different Antibiotic_Prescribed

Tags: sql-server

I'm using the following SQL Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       pa.regcode AS MRN,
       p.Age,
       (CASE WHEN p.GenderID = 1 THEN 'Male' WHEN p.GenderID = 2 THEN 'Female' ELSE 'Null' END) AS Sex,
       --d.DiseaseName as Diagnosis
       med.ITEMNAME AS Antibiotic_Prescribed,
       med.PRESCRIPTIONDATE,
       med.PRESCRIPTIONID,
       med.DOSE,
       CONCAT(med.DURATION, +' ' + med.DURATIONUOM) AS Duration,
       --ts.Name as Investgation,
       --c.Name as Component
       --r.Value as Investgation_Result
       dep.Name
FROM v_dbPatientAdmissions pa
     JOIN V_EPRIS_MEDICATION med ON med.ADMISSIONID = pa.AdmissionID
     JOIN v_dbEmpClinicCodes em ON em.EmpID = pa.ConsultantID
     JOIN v_dbEmployees emp ON emp.EmpID = pa.ConsultantID
     INNER JOIN v_dbPatientMonitoring pm ON pm.IPID = pa.AdmissionID
     INNER JOIN v_DBPatientDiseases pd ON pd.MonitorID = pm.MonitorID
     INNER JOIN v_dbDiseases d ON d.DiseaseID = pd.DiseaseID
     INNER JOIN v_dbNxGtestorderitems TOI ON TOI.AdmissionID = pa.AdmissionID
     INNER JOIN v_dbNxgtestorders TSO ON TSO.TestOrderID = TOI.TestOrderID
     INNER JOIN v_dbtestresults r ON r.TestOrderID = TSO.TestOrderID
     INNER JOIN V_Tests TS ON TS.TestId = TOI.TestID
     JOIN v_dbPatients p ON p.PatientID = pa.PatientID
     JOIN v_dbComponents c ON c.ComponentID = r.ComponentID
     JOIN v_dbDepartments dep ON dep.HospDeptId = TSO.ORDERDEPTID
WHERE (ITEMNAME LIKE '%AMOXYCILLINE%'
    OR itemname LIKE '%AZITHROMYCIN%'
    OR itemname LIKE '%CEFUROXIME%'
    OR itemname LIKE '%CEPHALEXIN%'
    OR itemname LIKE '%CHLOROQUIN PHOSPHATE%'
    OR itemname LIKE '%CIPROFLOXACIN%'
    OR itemname LIKE '%CLARITHROMYCIN%'
    OR itemname LIKE '%CO-AMOXICLAV%'
    OR itemname LIKE '%COTRIMOXAZOLE%'
    OR itemname LIKE '%FLUCLOXACILLINE%'
    OR itemname LIKE '%METRONIDAZOLE%'
    OR itemname LIKE '%NITROFURANTOIN%'
    OR itemname LIKE '%PENICILLIN-VK%'
    OR itemname LIKE '%TETRACYCLINE%'
    OR itemname LIKE '%CEFDINIR%'
    OR itemname LIKE '%CEFIXIME%'
    OR itemname LIKE '%ETHAMBUTOL%'
    OR itemname LIKE '%FLUCONAZOLE%'
    OR itemname LIKE '%ISONIAZIDE%'
    OR itemname LIKE '%ITRACONAZOL%'
    OR itemname LIKE '%LEVOFLOXACIN%'
    OR itemname LIKE '%MOXIFLOXACIN%'
    OR itemname LIKE '%NORFLOXACIN%'
    OR itemname LIKE '%PYRAZINAMIDE%'
    OR itemname LIKE '%RIFAMPICIN%'
    OR itemname LIKE '%SECNIDAZOLE%'
    OR itemname LIKE '%SOD.FUSIDATE%'
    OR itemname LIKE '%TERBINAFINE%'
    OR itemname LIKE '%VALACYCLOVIR%'
    OR itemname LIKE '%AMOXYCILLINE INJECTION%'
    OR itemname LIKE '%CEFAZOLIN INJECTION%'
    OR itemname LIKE '%CEFUROXIME SOD. INJECTION%'
    OR itemname LIKE '%CHLORAMPHENICOL INJECTION%'
    OR itemname LIKE '%CIPROFLOXACIN INJECTION%'
    OR itemname LIKE '%CO-AMOXICLAV INJECTION%'
    OR itemname LIKE '%COTRIMOXAZOLE INJECTION%'
    OR itemname LIKE '%ERYTHROMYCIN LACTOBIONATE INJECTION%'
    OR itemname LIKE '%FLUCLOXACILLINE INJECTION%'
    OR itemname LIKE '%METRONIDAZOLE INJECTION%'
    OR itemname LIKE '%PENICILLIN -G-SOD. INJECTION%'
    OR ITEMNAME LIKE '%AMPHOTERACIN- INJECTION%'
    OR ITEMNAME LIKE '%CEFOTAXIME%'
    OR ITEMNAME LIKE '%CEFTAZIDIME%'
    OR ITEMNAME LIKE '%CEFTRIAXONE%'
    OR ITEMNAME LIKE '%CLINDAMYCIN%'
    OR ITEMNAME LIKE '%COTRIMOXAZOLE%'
    OR ITEMNAME LIKE '%FLUCONAZOLE%'
    OR ITEMNAME LIKE '%LEVOFLOXACIN%'
    OR ITEMNAME LIKE '%MEROPENEM VIAL%'
    OR ITEMNAME LIKE '%MOXIFLOXACIN%'
    OR ITEMNAME LIKE '%PIPERACILLINE /TAZOBACTAM%'
    OR ITEMNAME LIKE '%SOD.FUSIDATE%'
    OR ITEMNAME LIKE '%SPECTINOMYCIN%'
    OR ITEMNAME LIKE '%STREPTOMYCIN%'
    OR ITEMNAME LIKE '%VANCOMYCIN HCL%'
    OR ITEMNAME LIKE '%AMIKACIN%'
    OR ITEMNAME LIKE '%GENTAMICIN %')
  AND (pa.AdmitDate >= '2019-01-01'
   AND pa.AdmitDate <= '2019-06-30')
  AND pa.PatientType = 1
  AND r.Value IS NOT NULL
  AND r.Value != ' '
  AND TS.name LIKE '%Culture%'
  AND (c.Name LIKE '%Microorganism%'
    OR c.Name LIKE '%Growth%');
```

That gives the following output:
[image]

I'm trying to retrieve the patient's with the duplicated  `'med.PRESCRIPTIONID'`, but different `'med.ITEMNAME'` (6 rows highlighted in the image as an example), in other words, I need to only retrieve the patient's who received more than one antibiotic in one prescription.

Comment: What have tried so far? What is the expected result set you're after hear; are you just after the patient's name, for example? Also, I'm not sure that `BETWEEN` works as you expect; for example `2019-06-30T00:00:01.000` is **not** between your 2 dates.

Comment: That volume of `LIKE` expressions with leading wildcards most also be awful for your queries' performance as well. It seems like the drug name and quantity type and quantity value should be (3) separate columns.

Comment: how about using WITH and doing self join where PRESCRIPTIONID = PRESCRIPTIONID and ITEMNAME <> ITEMNAME?

Comment: what about row `30 & 31` in your screen, why they are not considering in your output.

Comment: you're right , I've changed  the like expression with the wildcards to using the Medication itemID

Comment: row 30 & 31 are also considered but i just highlighted few rows as an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned that your above query give the result in above screenshot. So I'll start my query after that.

```
; with cte as (
...... Your query mentioned above...
)
, ct as (
select MRN, PRESCRIPTIONID, Antibiotic_Prescribed from cte group by MRN, PRESCRIPTIONID , Antibiotic_Prescribed
)
select MRN, PRESCRIPTIONID from ct 
group by  MRN, PRESCRIPTIONID 
having count(Antibiotic_Prescribed)>1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` function to assign numbers partitioned by PRESCRIPTIONID and Antibiotic_Prescribed .

```
WITH cte AS ( 
--your code and add rownumber column
  seq = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PRESCRIPTIONID, Antibiotic_Prescribed ORDER BY PRESCRIPTIONID)
 )
SELECT * from cte where seq = 1
```